# Convert current time(IST) to UTC using groovy script in SoapUI

Tags: groovy, soapui

I am new to Groovy script and I am looking for a groovy script in soapUI, where I can convert my current time (IST) to UTC before passing it to API.

I tried below code:

```
import java.util.*;

def d = new Date()
def CurrentDay = ('0' + d.getUTCDate()).slice(-2)
def CurrentMonth = ('0' + d.getUTCMonth()).slice(-2)
def CurrentYear = d.getUTCFullYear()
def CurrentHours = ('0' + d.getUTCHours()).slice(-2)
def CurrentMinutes = ('0' + d.getUTCMinutes()).slice(-2)
def CurrentSeconds = ('0' + d.getUTCSeconds()).slice(-2)
def DateFormatted = CurrentYear.toString() + CurrentMonth.toString() + CurrentDay.toString() + CurrentHours.toString() + CurrentMinutes.toString() + CurrentSeconds.toString()

return DateFormatted;
```

But it's not helping me. Looking forward for the help.

EDIT: OP commented in the answer that he wanted to have future time say 10 minutes later time.

Comment: Basu Raj, can you check the solution to see if that helps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert the local date to different time zone in simple way:

```
println new Date().format("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", TimeZone.getTimeZone('UTC'))
```

Of course, you can change the required *date format* as needed since you haven't mentioned.

In case if you need to send the same date in the Soap request, you do not have to have an additional `Groovy Script` test step to create the date. Instead, you can just use **in-line** code in the request itself as shown below:

Say, there is `date` element in the request

```
<date>${= new Date().format("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", TimeZone.getTimeZone('UTC'))}</date>
```

EDIT: Based on op comments; need to get the delayed time (10 minutes later from now)

```
<date>${= def date=new Date(); use(groovy.time.TimeCategory){date = date.plus(10.minutes)}; date.format("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", TimeZone.getTimeZone('UTC'))}</date>
```

The above should work. However, SoapUI seems to have issue parsing the above.
The workaround is to use a groovy script test step before request step  as shown below :

```
def date=new Date()
use(groovy.time.TimeCategory){ date = date.plus(10.minutes) }
def dateString = date.format("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", TimeZone.getTimeZone('UTC'))
context.testCase.setPropertyValue('FUTURE_TIME', dateString)
```

In the request body, use `<date>${#TestCase#FUTURE_TIME}</date>`

Comment: Hey Rao, This information is very useful and it helped me to optimize my code. Thanks.

Comment: Glad that i you find it useful.

Comment: Using this single line code i will get converted UTC time, So now if i want to add +10 mins to the the converted time? How to achieve that?

Comment: Sure Rao, My requerment  is, to schedule some task in future time. To do that i need to pick current time(IST) add extra 15 or 30 mins and then covert it to UST and then pass it to API. And also let me how to pass this from request body?

Comment: @BasuRaj, can you check the edit part of the answer to see if that is helpful? Appreciate [upvotes](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) for the helpful answer

Answer (score 1):

With `SimpleDateFormatter` you can set the `TimeZone`:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

def d = new Date()
def sdf = new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"))
println("IST ${sdf.format(d)}")
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))
println("UTC ${sdf.format(d)}")
```